# Placing GSM calls keeps disconnecting emulator from ADB

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I am currently working on an Android project but I have a problem.

I'm using Android Studio and the Android Emulator and every time I place a GSM call to the emulator, ADB loses connection to the device and I have to restart ADB to get the device detected again. The call does get placed to the emulator though.

It's causing me problems as I am trying to debug a bit of code that I have written that is fired when a call is detected but because ADB disconnects the emulator every time I can't step through the code in debug mode.

Answer (score 4):

This is an extremely annoying problem, and I've been wrestling with it, ESPECIALLY since the app I am writing initializes upon receipt of a call.

The quickest way to get back up and running, without restarting the emulator, is to have a second terminal window open (or exit the telnet session for a few seconds) and run:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Or, alternatively:

```
adb kill-server;adb start-server
```

...if you'd like to run it at once.

After a few seconds, you'll be reconnected. I've spent several hours searching for a way to actually PREVENT the disconnect in the first place, but I don't think it's possible until they fix the bug.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I've been doing, but I was having a problem which I needed to debug and step through the code, annoyingly though this isn't possible due to the emulator disconnecting from ADB each time I place a call

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to update your Android SDK? Update it and create new virtual device. Maybe that can help you.

Comment: I've unfortunately started getting this problem since I've updated the SDK and ADT plugin. I updated it for when KitKit 4.4 was released.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try genymotion? Much better emulator than the standard one. http://www.genymotion.com/ At least that way you can rule out the standard emulator, narrow it down to adb

Answer (score 0):

Man,

I was having the same problem. The Genymotion would be a great option but they don't support mobile networking (gsm calls) now.

The first API working for was not 18 neither 19 (both updated) but 16.

So try it with 16 and it is working like charm. I am goin to try 17 too.

Good luck!